# C# Save user input as binary

Tags: c#, binary, decimal, converters

So I just learned how to convert ints to binary with `Convert.ToString(int , 2);`

Now I can use this so ask a user for a number and then save it with

```
int name = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

and then convert it with

```
Convert.ToString(name , 2);
```

to get the number in binary.

But I'm wondering if the user could input it in binary and then I could save it as is, to later convert the user input into decimal with

```
Convert.ToInt32(binary,2).ToString();
```

I know this isn't correct but just to give you an idea of what I'm looking for here is an example,  instead of int you could use binary. Like

```
binary name = binary.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Binary`? Do you mean `string`?

Comment: ^ you don't read binary from console, you only get strings/chars.

Comment: The input from keyboard is Always a string so no, the user can't insert data in binary, but you can save the strings and convert them later, to do so you can parse for numeric strings, put them in an array of strings and then use the File.WriteAllLines(file, collection) to write all strings on disk and then you can read the file and create the numbers.

Comment: I meant it as a hypothetical replacement to int in the  int name = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); I know it doesn't exists, it was just to give you an ideo of what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm in a basic c# class and have an assignment for creating three basic programs, one which converts user inputs from decimal to binary and hexadecimal, one which converts binary to decimal and hexadecimal and one which converts hexadecimal to binary and decimal. I can do these if I leave out the part where the user is supposed to input the number but thats supposed to be in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're slightly confused - when you "convert int's to binary" all you're actually doing is converting the `int` into a `string` in it's *binary representation*. It's not actually binary - it's just a string that contains 1's and 0's that represent a binary number.

To accomplish your goal, all you need to do is:

```
string binary = Console.ReadLine();
```

And the user would need to enter "binary" such as `0100`. Again, I put binary in quotes because it's still just a string, not a number. If you want the user to enter a number, like `4` and store it as a string of `0100`, just do:

```
string binary = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), 2);
```

which will read the user input (4), convert it to an integer, and then convert it to it's string binary representation (`0100`).

To read it back to an `int`, do `Convert.ToInt32(binary, 2);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really cleared up my confusion on the matter :)

Answer (score 1):

You will read a string input from Console.ReadLine - but you can just use [`Convert.ToInt32(val, 2)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert a base 2 string to a number.

If you really want to create a binary number type, you will need to define a struct with implicit or explicit conversion to an int, but this seems unneccessary for your task. But, they key point here is that an `int` is kind of base agnostic - it's the value represented by a string in base whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate :)